# Postman Status: 304 from POST request JERSEY

Tags: java, mysql, jersey

I've been trying to build CRUD operation with Jersey and now I have status: 304 Not Modified.

My code worked on the laptop but when I transferred the same code on my pc this error suddenly appeared.

I was trying to do a POST request to add JSON input into my MySQL workbench database.

**My database connection service:**

```
package com.common.db;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;


public class MysqlDbConnectionService {
    public Connection tryToGetConnectionTwice() throws Exception {
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sampledb";
        String user = "root";
        String password = "admin";
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
        System.out.println("Connection is Successful to the database " + url);
        return connection;
    }
    public Connection getConnection() throws Exception {
        Connection connection=null;
        try {
            connection=tryToGetConnectionTwice();
        }catch (Exception e ){

        }
        if (connection==null)
            return tryToGetConnectionTwice();
        else return connection;
    }
}
```

**Here is my StudentResource:**

```
package com.resources;


import com.common.db.domain.Student;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.services.StudentService;

import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import java.sql.SQLException;


@Path("students")
public class StudentResource {

    @POST
    public Response save(String payload) {
        Student student = new Gson().fromJson(payload, Student.class);
        StudentService studentService = new StudentService();
        try {
            boolean studentSaved = studentService.saveStudent(student);
            if (studentSaved) {
                return Response.ok(new Gson().toJson(student)).build();
            } else {
                return Response.notModified().build();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            return Response.serverError().build();
        }
    }
}
```

**Here is my student service:**

```
package com.services;

import com.common.db.MysqlDbConnectionService;
import com.common.db.domain.Student;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class StudentService {


    public boolean saveStudent(Student student) throws SQLException {
        if (student == null) {
            return false;
        }
        Connection connection = null;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        try {
            connection = new MysqlDbConnectionService().getConnection();
            ps = connection.prepareStatement("insert into users(user_id,username,password,fullname,email) values (?,?,?,?,?)");
            ps.setString(1, student.getId());
            ps.setString(2, student.getUsername());
            ps.setString(3, student.getPassword());
            ps.setString(4, student.getFullName());
            ps.setString(5, student.getEmail());
            ps.executeUpdate();
            ps.close();
            connection.close();
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            connection.close();
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you check mysql table to see if has any data?

Comment: Postman doesn't let me put the JSON string to insert the data into the database

Comment: Also I have the same database name and table name in my laptop and pc

Comment: The fact that's there's a 304 is not the issue. _You_ are the one setting the 304 with `Response.notModified()`. That's what a 304 status code means "Not Modified".

Comment: Should I delete the Response.notModified()?

Comment: you do `e.printStackTrace()` and you should see the stacktrace in the serverlog somewhere.

Comment: Can you explain to me why I can't put JSON string to insert through postman into the database.

Comment: Look at the logic of your code. If there is an exception, you return false. That's what leads to Response.notModified(). You need to see what the exception is and fix it.

Comment: Paul do you have a discord channel so I can ask you more about java and jersey.